# mongodb: how to update array element by index number

Tags: mongodb

Suppose you have documents like this:

```
{
    _id: 'sdsdfsd',
    a: [
          { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }
          { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }
          { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }
          { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }
    ]
}
```

So, if you have the `_id` and an index number (say: 2). Now, for that index I want to change the `x` value to 1. Is this possible in mongo or should I first retrieve the whole array, update the specific value and update the whole array by inserting it back ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access a specific array element in an `update` by its 0-based index using dot-notation:

```js
// Set the x property of the third element of a to 1
db.test.update({_id: 'sdsdfsd'}, {$set: {'a.2.x': 1}})
```

Answer (score 1):

Else you can go further, you can construct your way to the value with the variable indexes. Use string template

```
   yourModel.findOneAndUpdate(
     { _id: "sdsdfsd" },
     {
       $set: {
         [`a.${index}.x`]: newValue,
       },
     }
   );
```